# d3-geo: Find centroid inside multiple geometries

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I'm using **react-simple-maps** to show show some data on USA map and I need to group states by some criteria. Each group should have own marker. I've got geographies for each state, so I need to merge somehow coordinates of each state in one and find centroid.

I don't know how to do that. Currently I just take bounds (**d3-geo:geoBounds**) of each state in group and calculate center simply by taking the min max from each bound for top left right bottom and find the center of this big area.

```
let geosBounds = geos.filter(g => !excludeZones.includes(g.properties.code)).map(g => geoBounds(g))
if (geosBounds.length === 0 && geos.some(g => excludeZones.includes(g.properties.code)) && geos.length === 1) {
  return separateZoneCenters[geos[0].properties.code]
}
const totalArea = geosBounds.reduce((acc, [[x0, y0],[x1, y1]]) => ({
  x0: acc.hasOwnProperty('x0') ? Math.min(acc.x0, x0) : x0,
  x1: acc.hasOwnProperty('x1') ? Math.max(acc.x1, x1) : x1,
  y0: acc.hasOwnProperty('y0') ? Math.min(acc.y0, y0) : y0,
  y1: acc.hasOwnProperty('y1') ? Math.max(acc.y1, y1) : y1,
}), {})
return [
  (totalArea.x1 +  totalArea.x0)  / 2,
  (totalArea.y1 +  totalArea.y0) / 2
];
```

So I've got something like this in the end:

[result example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZOsw.png)

could you please suggest me how to merge geographies into one and find a proper centroid to place a marker inside a group?

Answer (score 0):

So, I found one solution with using topojson:

```
const merged = topojson.merge(states, states.objects.states.geometries.filter(geo => group.states.includes(geo.properties.code)))
const centroid = geoCentroid(merged)
return {
  coordinates: centroid,
}
```

[how it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfTUg.png)

And it looks good! But maybe there are some other solutions for that?